# Accpt employee number from user fetch the employee details from the “Employee” table and store it to a PLSQL record type variable and print the same

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Accpt employee number from user fetch the employee details from the “Employee” table and store it to a  PLSQL record type variable and print the same.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    DECLARE
    type emp_det is record
    (
    emp_num number := &empnum,
    emp_name varchar2(150),
    emp_sal number,
    dept_id number
    );
    emp_rec emp_det;
    BEGIN
    select employee_id, first_name, salary, department_id into emp_num, emp_name,
    emp_sal, dept_id from hr.employees where employee_id = &empnum;
    dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||emp_rec.emp_num);
    dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||emp_rec.emp_name);
    dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||emp_rec.emp_sal);
    dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||emp_rec.dept_id);
    END;
```

Comment: This is a good place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option (if that's what you're looking for):

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_empno in emp.empno%type) is
  2    type emp_det is record (empno number,
  3                            ename varchar2(10),
  4                            sal   number
  5                           );
  6    led  emp_det;
  7  begin
  8    select empno, ename, sal
  9      into led
 10      from emp
 11      where empno = par_empno;
 12
 13    dbms_output.put_line(led.empno ||': '|| rpad(led.ename, 10, ' ') || led.sal);
 14  end;
 15  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test(7369);
7369: SMITH     800

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a record or procedure and can use `%TYPE` to get the column data types:

```sql
DECLARE
  emp_num  HR.EMPLOYEES.EMPLOYEE_ID%TYPE := &empnum;
  emp_name HR.EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
  emp_sal  HR.EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
  dept_id  HR.EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT employee_id,
         first_name,
         salary,
         department_id
  INTO   emp_num,
         emp_name,
         emp_sal,
         dept_id
  FROM   hr.employees
  WHERE  employee_id = emp_num;

  dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||emp_num);
  dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||emp_name);
  dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||emp_sal);
  dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||dept_id);
END;
/
```

If you *must* (you really do not need to) use a record then `SELECT ... INTO` the record:

```sql
DECLARE
  -- Declare the record type.
  TYPE employee_record IS RECORD(
    emp_num  NUMBER,              -- You cannot set a default value.
    emp_name VARCHAR2(150),
    emp_sal  NUMBER,
    dept_id  NUMBER
  );

  -- Declare an instance of the record.
  emp_rec employee_record;
BEGIN
  SELECT employee_id,  -- Columns in the same order as the record.
         first_name,
         salary,
         department_id
  INTO   emp_rec       -- Into the record instance.
  FROM   hr.employees
  WHERE  employee_id = &empnum;

  dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||emp_rec.emp_num);
  dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||emp_rec.emp_name);
  dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||emp_rec.emp_sal);
  dbms_output.put_line('Employee Number :'||emp_rec.dept_id);
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=23e255d20d70e45e00c98d850e73178b)*